# MySQL Logical grouping of tables

Tags: mysql

I am coming from MSSQL world and learning MySQL now. I see that `schema` and `database` is same in MySQL, however these are different in MSSQL.

I want to logically group my tables as can be done using `schema` in MSSQL. How can I achieve this?

**Edit 1**

As per comments, I can't use `schema` to logically group my tables. Is there any other system which I can use? Maybe using a prefix in table names?

**Edit 2**

My use case is, I am designing a big software which would have multiple modules. Each of the modules would have multiple tables. I want these tables segregated from each other. Although all the tables would be used for this software only, but they should be kept apart. E.g. Employee module tables should be separate from Inventory module tables.

Comment: Simple answer: you can't. MySQL only supports a single level of namespace.

Comment: Well, you could put tables that logically belong together in different databases; however, then I assume you'd need to logically group certain databases together. Including a prefix on the table name works, but would have to be maintained manually. If you have a specific reason why there are subgroups of tables, we might be able to make better suggestions. There's a big difference between `DeptA` and DeptB`, and `Dev` and `Prd`, for instance.

Comment: As a long time MySQL user, I have not found a need for an extra layer of grouping.  What is your use case?

Answer (score -3):

i like to tell you in mysql , its also `schema` and `database` are different things.

`schema` is present under `database`.

means in two different `database`, same named `schema` may present.

i.e; in any one `database` this may possible -

```
create new schema sch1;
CREATE TABLE sch1.pet (name VARCHAR(20), owner VARCHAR(20),

create new schema sch2;
CREATE TABLE sch2.pet (name VARCHAR(20), owner VARCHAR(20),
```

in any 2nd `database` which having different connection ip have

above same schema  and  may possibly present..

Comment: Schema and database are **not** different things in MySQL. [Quote from the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-database.html): "*CREATE SCHEMA is a synonym for CREATE DATABASE*". Your example simply creates two new databases called `sch1` and `sch2`

Comment: How do I create a database then?

Comment: @Aakash with `CREATE DATABASE`. Just forget about schemas, MySQL doesn't have them