# MySQL: Hierarchical Organization of Tables

Tags: mysql, database-design, tablespaces, hierarchy

There are several SE Q&As regarding how to hierarchically organize tables in MySQL:

- [How to use a naming convention for large databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603120/how-to-use-a-naming-convention-for-large-databases)
  <sup>Asked 12 years, 11 months ago</sup>
- [How can I organize a glut of mysql tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217157/how-can-i-organize-a-glut-of-mysql-tables)
  <sup>Asked 12 years, 3 months ago</sup>
- [Grouping tables within a MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465468/grouping-tables-within-a-mysql-database)
  <sup>Asked 12 years, 2 months ago</sup>
- [Is it possible to organize tables or others object in folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226247/is-it-possible-to-organize-tables-or-others-object-in-folder)
  <sup>Asked 9 years, 3 months ago</sup>
- [How to organize MySQL tables names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33028910/how-to-organize-mysql-tables-names)
  <sup>Asked 7 years, 4 months ago</sup>
- [MySQL Logical grouping of tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/173417/mysql-logical-grouping-of-tables)
  <sup>Asked 5 years, 9 months ago</sup>
- [MySQL namespace in create table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57885126/mysql-namespace-in-create-table)
  <sup>Asked 3 years, 5 months ago</sup>

Most answers revolve around something like:

- There is no concept of hierarchy in MySQL (ie: no folders, containers nor namespaces for the databases).
- One solution is to keep related tables together by naming conventions (ex: use the same prefix `hr_` for tables primarily related to Human Resources).
- One hack is to use different databases for different sets of tables. However, this can create more problems than it is worth.
- "I have not found a need for an extra layer of grouping.", *a long time MySQL user*

#### Questions

1. Notice that the Q&As links above are considerably old (3~13yo).
   Are the aforementioned answers still up to date?
2. Regarding the "hack" of using different databases for different sets of tables.
   What are the pros and cons?
3. Some databases have namespaces (ex: PostgreSQL) which can be used like:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM articles;
   SELECT * FROM articles.comments;
   SELECT * FROM articles.author;
   ```

   Is there any reason why MySQL doesn't have any such features?
   How does the MySQL's devs expect users to "organize a glut of mysql tables"?

Comment: @RickJames > "What version are you running?" mariadb 10.3~10.5

Comment: @RickJames > "I still say that about DATABASE and TABLE" hummm ... at some point naming tables will get confuse. Maybe your limit is higher than other people (ex: you can deal up to 1000 tables while most people get confused at 100). What is you limit?

Comment: @RickJames > 'For hierarchical, you need "CTEs" ' At a first glance, it seems that CTEs resembles somewhat subqueries and derived tables, but using an WITH clause. Very helpful indeed. However, IMHO I still miss the namespaces as shown of PostgreSQL.

Comment: @RickJames > "What have you found beneficial about namespaces?" This is a well known issue in CS. Just to name a few: "Within the namespace of the Doe family, just 'Jane' suffices to unambiguously designate this person", _Wikipedia_

Comment: @BillKarwin > "MySQL does support schemas as a namespace" Ok, as mentioned in the links I've posted: "One hack is to use different databases for different sets of tables. However, this can create more problems than it is worth." What are the pros and cons of doing it this way?

Comment: The user who claimed that schemas would create problems was basing that on a wrong assumption that you couldn't join tables from different schemas. In fact, in MySQL you can join tables in different schemas. You can make foreign keys that reference a table in another schema. They just don't know what they're talking about. They admitted that they don't use MySQL so they were truly talking out of their hat.

Comment: I don't think there is any con to using schemas that isn't exactly the same as separating tables by using a naming convention.